# Formulate LABS problem as QUBO

Tags: oc.optimization-and-control, quadratic-programming

I'm trying to formulate the LABS (low autocorrelation binary sequences) as a QUBO (quadratic unconstrained binary optimisation). The LABS problem is as follows:
Given a sequence $s_i \in \{-1,1\} $, define $C_k(S) = \sum_{i=1}^{N-k} s_is_{i+k}$, minimise $E(S) = \sum_{k=1}^{N-1} C_{k}^{2}(S)$.

I want to formulate LABS as QUBO, which is generally defined as: $x^TQx$ for some matrix $Q$. If $x \in \{-1,1\}^N$ and $Q$ is a strict lower triangular matrix, with ones as entries, $x^TQx = \sum_{k=1}^{N-1} C_{k}(S) $. Sadly, I don't see, how I could define $Q$, to get the square over $C_k$. I can formulate $ E(S) = x^TQxx^TQ^Tx$ but I don't think, that would be considered a QUBO. For any input, if this is possible and if how, I would be very thankful.